# Not able to Map over Fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am not able to map over the data which is stored in the redux array.
This action creator fetches the data and calls the dispatch action.

```js
import { checkStatus, getTours, checkLoading } from "../../features/tourSlice";
   
export const getData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(checkLoading(true));
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/backpack/api/r1/tours`);
    
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error while connecting with server`);
      }

      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch(checkLoading(false));
      dispatch(getTours(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        checkStatus({
          title: `Error`,
          message: `Servers are down or Error while connecting please try again later`,
        })
      );
    }
  };
};
```

calling in app.js

```js
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

while using this component gives nothing.

```js
const data = useSelector((state) => state.Tour.tours);
```

but doing console.log of data gives the array but gives nothing when maping over

small example of mapping=>

```html
<main className="main">
        <div className="card-container">
          {data.map((item) => (
            <div className="card" key={item._id}>
              {console.log(item)}
              <div className="card__header">
                <div className="card__picture">
                  <div className="card__picture-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
                  <img
                    src=`${item.image}`
                    alt="Tour 1"
                    className="card__picture-img"
                  />
```

Comment: what does the console.log data look like

Comment: Have you tried applying optional chaining or conditional operator? sometimes the data takes some time to load and since you are having the data in the console, this might solve the issue. It would be better if you could have added the mapping logic to your question.

Comment: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] this is output of console which exactly what i need but mapping over it gives nothing @Sean

Comment: you need to provide more code and how you map over the data

Comment: well ? will dosenot do anything as initialstate is not null or undefined its empty array @AbdullahAnsari

Comment: add it to the original question with proper formatting

Comment: ok please check updated question @Sean

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: no console give me response that i am getting @yousoumar

Comment: Try running `data.map(item => console.log(item))`